# Using toString when setting object prototype to null

Tags: javascript, prototype, defineproperty, writable

If I set the prototype to null, then how come I can still use toString on the object?

```
var nakedObject=Object.create(null,{
name:{
    configurable:true,
    enumerable:true,
    value:"Hello",
    writable:true
}
});
 console.log(nakedObject.name.toString());
 console.log ("valueOf" in nakedObject);
```

Comment: because nakedObject.name is a string. And it is inherited from String prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The `nakedObject` doesn't have a prototype anymore, but the property `.name` still does. And because you assigned it the value `"Hello"` it is a String, therefore it has the String prototype.